# plotting issue with python: NameError: name 'month' is not defined

Tags: python

Data

```
icp reading_date    manufacturer_serial_number  reading consumption_kwh month
114 0000000482NT9A0 2021-02-01  NTL1504130  1691.753    0.814   2021-02
115 0000000482NT9A0 2021-02-01  NTL1504130  2834.073    1.611   2021-02
116 0000000482NT9A0 2021-02-01  NTL1504130  3568.006    0.235   2021-02
230 0000000482NT9A0 2021-02-02  NTL1504130  2834.073    0.000   2021-02
229 0000000482NT9A0 2021-02-02  NTL1504130  1691.753    0.000   2021-02
```

the code I used:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(month, reading, color='red', marker='o')
plt.show()
```

and I got an error message:

```
NameError: name 'month' is not defined
```

Comment: This means that the variable `month` that you want to plot is not defined

Comment: You haven't read your data into python. Is it a CSV file? You need to get data into "month" and "reading" variables, then you can plot.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined a variable "month". You need to read the data and put it into a variable that you can use for plotting. `pandas` is an option. Suppose your data is in a file "data.txt". You could read it into pandas and the columns will be available by name. Since you're plotting multiple values on 1 date, its going to be an odd looking graph.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep='\s+')
plt.plot(df['month'], df['reading'], color='red', marker='o')
plt.show()
```

Comment: oops, thanks heaps, it's working now :)